# Regular Expression split w/ Lookbehind loses second half

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, split

I have a string that contains a number of keywords. I would like to split the string into a list of those keywords (but keep the keywords because they identify what the following data means)

Take the following string for example:

```
test_string = "ªttypmp3pfilfDjTunes/DJ Music/(I've Had) The Time Of My Life.mp3tsng<(I've Had) The Time Of My Lifetart:Bill Medley & Jennifer Warnes"
```

the important keywords are "ttyp", "pfil", "tsng", "tart". I would like to split the file so the output looks:

```
split_test_string = ["ª","ttypmp3","pfilfDjTunes/DJ Music/(I've Had) The Time Of My Life.mp3","tsng<(I've Had) The Time Of My Life","tart:Bill Medley & Jennifer Warnes"].
```

I've been researching regular expressions, and I think this expression would work, but when tested in Python, I end up losing the part that I want to keep. According to the Python re.split documents, this should work.

Checkout my regex calculator: https://regex101.com/r/FOlgv8/1

Note: I'm trying to get the first part to work. Then I'll add the rest of the keywords using |.

```
regex = r'(?=ttyp).*'
```

This is my example code:

```
import re
regex = r'(?=ttyp).*'

split_test_string = re.split(regex, test_string)
print(f"Results: {split_test_string}")
```

Console Output:

```
Results: ['ª', '']
```

I've tried positive lookahead and positive lookback with no luck. I could just use a literal 'ttyp' but then I lose the keyword.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been researching, trial and erroring (mostly erroring) for hours now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
re.split("(?=ttyp|pfil|tsng|tart)", test_string)
```

The reason yours didn't work is that you split by `.*`, meaning you capture everything after the separator and treat it as the seperator itself (and thus throw it).

Comment: Geez. Regex are so confusing. So let me make sure I understand. The regex, returns the delimiter, not the string that I want to keep?

Comment: [This doesn't work at all](https://rextester.com/PJK3785), because `re.split` won't capture anything if the pattern is zero width.  Use `re.findall` instead as a workaround.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry lad, it works. That's a bug in rextester. Reason it works is that it splits on a zero width pattern.

Comment: @Chaky31 The regex checks in each position if there's anything in the future matching one of the patterns. If there is, it matches that position (zero width match) and splits.

Comment: When I try running your code locally in Python 3.6, I get: `ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Try a more up-to-date version like 3.9

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh here ya go Tim. That's a bug that was solved in 3.7 https://bugs.python.org/issue25054.

Changelog - https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#re

3.6 is so 2016 :-P

Comment: And rextester uses 3.6.9. They should consider updating. Lots of changes to the `re` module lately.

Comment: Just as a bit of extra info. I wanted to see which of the three answers presented was the most efficient. In practice, I'm running this script on a list of 8,000 strings (with the potential of running 100,000 strings).

This method was the fastest, handing 8,000 strings in 149 seconds.
Method 2 submitted by Lionel Foxcroft took 231 seconds
Method 3 submitted by Time Biegeleisen took 220 seconds.

Tested using Timeit, each method was run 100 times.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex based solution using `re.findall`:

```py
test_string = "ªttypmp3pfilfDjTunes/DJ Music/(I've Had) The Time Of My Life.mp3tsng<(I've Had) The Time Of My Lifetart:Bill Medley & Jennifer Warnes"
keywords = ["ttyp", "pfil", "tsng", "tart"];
regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + r'|$)';
matches = re.findall(r'.+?' + r'(?=' + regex + r')', test_string)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['\xc2\xaa', 'ttypmp3', "pfilfDjTunes/DJ Music/(I've Had) The Time Of My Life.mp3",
 "tsng<(I've Had) The Time Of My Life", 'tart:Bill Medley & Jennifer Warnes']
```

The strategy here is to match all content up to, but not including, anyone of the 4 keywords which you identified.  Note that we need to make the Python script UTF-8 friendly in this case as your have some UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. UTF-8 is not possible for me, as the source of the string is from a vendor who chose mac-roman. It's kinda annoying to work with. But I like the approach of the keywords being in a list. That is a clean and easy to read advantage

Answer (score 0):

```py
from re import split
regex = '((?:ttyp|pfil|tsng|tart).*?)(?=ttyp|pfil|tsng|tart|$)'
test_string = "ªttypmp3pfilfDjTunes/DJ Music/(I've Had) The Time Of My Life.mp3tsng<(I've Had) The Time Of My Lifetart:Bill Medley & Jennifer Warnes"
matches = [x for x in split(regex, test_string) if x]
print(matches)
```

The way it works is that it matches the keyword you want, followed by the minimal number of additional characters needed to hit another keyword, or the end of the string. Afterwards, I filtered out the empty string from the list, so it would match what you wanted. You can see for yourself what happens if you don't do that.

Comment: I'm curious why you have 'matches' using in a list comprehension? Is that necessary? Based on some initials tests, this method is 38% slower, and the only differences I see are in the list comprehension and the regex. Since I have to do this 100,0000 times. That's significant.

Comment: The list comprehension filters out the empty string, because I included `if x`. Otherwise, the list will have the empty string in between each match.